# WinForms ShowInTaskbar=False vs Tabbing between applications

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a WinForms application (VB.Net), where I have set ShowInTaskbar=False for all forms except the main form. This is because all other forms are dialog windows of some sort, and I did not want them to show up separately in the task bar.

What I see now is that when no dialog is open in my application and I use Alt+Tab keys to tab between currently open applications, I don't see a tile for my application. I do see a tile when there is a dialog open. This is very counter-intuitive to me.

As I said earlier, ShowInTaskbar property is true for my main form. What else is required? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research, I found that my problem was being caused due to having the form border as FixedToolWindow and ShowInTaskbar=False on the dialog windows. I changed the form border to FixedDialog, and set MaximizeButton=False, MinimizeButton=False. That fixed the issue.